# Update query works in php my admin but not in php script

Tags: php, joomla, sql-update

I am having a problem with a script that im trying to create, it updates some params in a joomla cms website. If I make the updates in phpmyadmin and then press go it says :

```
    UPDATE  `websit52_rcsetch`.`u5b0y_modules` SET  `params` = '{"moduleclass_sfx":"demovideos","youtube_id":"XM0aLFaij8I3","width":"300","height":"200","responsive":"1","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"itemid"}' WHERE `u5b0y_modules`.`id` =192;
```

so I think, ok il just copy that query and put it into php and change the params to what I need.

so end up with :

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE  `websit52_rcsetch`.`u5b0y_modules` SET  `params` = '{"moduleclass_sfx":"demovideos","youtube_id":"XM0aLFaij8I3","width":"300","height":"200","responsive":"1","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"itemid"}' WHERE `u5b0y_modules`.`id` =192;")or die(mysql_error());
```

The problem is now on that line in Dreamweaver I am getting a red error warning on that line, but all I have done is literally copied the query into the mysqli query, so cant see why it wouldnt work ?. It says there is a syntax error, which I presume is caused by the double quotes that the params use, but im not sure if I can escape these without it effecting the query ?, or is there something else causing the problem ?.

Comment: this seems to remove the error, but not sure if it will work with all the escaping going on : mysql_query("UPDATE  `websit52_rcsetch`.`u5b0y_modules` SET  `params` = '{\"moduleclass_sfx\":\"demovideos\",\"youtube_id\":\"XM0aLFaij8I3\",\"width\":\"300\",\"height\":\"200\",\"responsive\":\"1\",\"cache\":\"1\",\"cache_time\":\"900\",\"cachemode\":\"itemid\"}' WHERE `u5b0y_modules`.`id` =192;")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You're using Joomla so make full use of the Joomla database API. Do **not** use `mysql_query`. This is deprecated. Please read the Joomla Documentation for database queries: http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: I know it is, but im just doing my job, iv not been asked to re program the whole website using mysqli or pdo, just to add something to it.

Comment: Joomla's database API supports PDO **and** mysqli. You don't need to manually define them, the API will cater the for the database engine you have defined so that no code changes will have to be made ;)

Comment: Its a custom script thats already written thats in php, it is wrapped inside a joomla wrapper, it interfaces with the joomla database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `websit52_rcsetch`.`u5b0y_modules` SET  `params` = '{\"moduleclass_sfx\":\"demovideos\",\"youtube_id\":\"XM0aLFaij8I3\",\"width\":\"300",\"height":\"200\",\"responsive\":\"1\",\"cache\":\"1\",\"cache_time\":\"900\",\"cachemode\":\"itemid\"}' WHERE `u5b0y_modules`.`id` =192;")or die(mysql_error());
```

In Joomla synthax :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Fields to update.
$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('params') . ' = ' . $db->quote('{"moduleclass_sfx":"demovideos","youtube_id":"XM0aLFaij8I3","width":"300","height":"200","responsive":"1","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"itemid"}')
);

// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 192'
);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__modules'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->query();
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and is also not Joomla based ;)

Comment: Thanks thats sorted it :)